# How to prevent exception logs of malformed requests in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

Spring Boot 2.6.x

```
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]: 2022-05-11 14:08:41.239  INFO 1831 --- [nio-2023-exec-7] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:  Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0xff0x0a0x00D0x000x080xc10xff...]. HTTP method names must be tokens
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419)
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:271)
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
May 11 14:08:41 ubuntu java[1831]:         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]: 2022-05-11 14:39:04.939  INFO 1831 --- [nio-2023-exec-3] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:  Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol [RTSP/1.00x0d0x0a0x0d0x0a...]
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:570)
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:271)
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
May 11 14:39:04 ubuntu java[1831]:         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Note the abnormal parts:

`method name [0xff0x0a0x00D0x000x080xc10xff...]`,

`HTTP protocol [RTSP/1.00x0d0x0a0x0d0x0a...]`

These must be randomly incoming attacking requests.

Is there any way to prevent these exception logs?

Comment: I received the same RTSP/1.0 error in my development environment (Eclipse 2022-03, Tomcat 8.5.85, Spring 4.3.30, Firefox 113.02, Windows 10). I'm not sure what is sending these requests, but it wasn't coming from outside my local environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a service that restarts quite often? Like, you get a request that starts-up Tomcat, then shuts-down, only to restart for another request after that?

Tomcat will only log the message you see above once per run at the `INFO` level, and those after that will be logged at the `DEBUG` level (just like the message says):

```
Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

So it won't log every error... just the first error for each time the HttpProcessor is re-initialized.

If these log messages become a nuisance, you have a few options:

1. Investigate why you are getting broken requests like this and try to minimize them (fix a broken client? use a firewall?)
2. Keep Tomcat running for longer; you will get fewer errors on your log
3. Set the log level for the org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor logger to `ERROR`